# Synchronous replication of databases

Tags: database, postgres

Say we have a software system with a web server serving writes to a Master DB. This Master DB is then replicated to several read-only DB replicas.

From my understanding, the process of asynchronous replication is fairly straightforward.

- The user posts a write request to the web server.
- Once this request is processed by the web server, the web server will shoot back a confirmation to the user, while (simultaneously) serving this write to the Master DB.
- The web server will not wait for the Master DB to confirm the write.

However, how would this process work in synchronous replication?

Upon receiving the write request from the user, the web server would still first serve the write request to the Master DB. Would the web server first wait for a confirmation from the Master DB (which would also require confirmations from the several read replicas), before sending a confirmation back to the user?

Is this process built-in to the database software (say PostgreSQL Master-Slave replication), or is there a degree of application code involved too?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what are the consistency requirements? Is a slave permitted to return an outdated value after a write has completed? Or is eventual consistency enough?

Comment: If eventual consistency is enough, then I'd assume the write would be automatically confirmed by the web server? But if strong consistency is required, then the web server would wait for the write to be confirmed by the Master (and Slave) dbs?

Comment: What would the trade-off be in the case of the latter? Would it be essentially trading latency (of the write) for strong consistency?

Comment: Your description of asynchronous replication is not how things typically work. Normally, an application will wait until the master node has confirmed that it has committed the change, before returning anything to the end user.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up Jory!

Answer (score 2):

> Upon receiving the write request from the user, the web server would still first serve the write request to the Master DB. Would the web server first wait for a confirmation from the Master DB (which would also require confirmations from the several read replicas), before sending a confirmation back to the user?

If we take the term synchronous requirement literally then the master would need to confirm the change before the transaction can be considered complete.  If all nodes are expected to be in-sync, then the updates would need to confirmed by all nodes before the transaction is considered complete.  The exact mechanisms of that could vary.

The obvious challenge with such a requirement is that if a node is unreachable, the entire cluster becomes read-only.  If you are not familiar with the [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), I recommend you take some time to read about it.

You might also want to look at [how DynamoDB handles consistency concerns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html). It's from the perspective of reads instead of writes but it's relevant to the larger concepts that you are asking about.

Comment: Those are some really interesting points.

In the case of just one Master, and several replicas, is it feasible to mandate synchronicity for JUST the web server -> Master write component, and then allow for asynchronous/eventual consistency of the replicas?

Thanks for the information, and also for the further reading links.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's a pretty typical approach.  There are all kinds of different approaches to this problem.  There are various databases and messaging systems that choose different trade-offs.  If you search on the CAP theorem and follow related articles, you should find examples.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! And yep, I'll do that.